# Bison syntax error from nowhere

Tags: c, parsing, syntax-error, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a compiler using FLEX and Bison.
As input i have a simple program.

```
DECLARE
    a b
IN
        GET a;
        b := 5 + a;
        a := b + 3; 
END
```

In my `parser.y` i am using  a integer subsidiary variable `counter`
When I assigning zero  to it i am getting `syntax error` I have no idea why this small change can make my program crush. It has nothing to do with `syntax!` I would be grateful to experienced people with C and Bison who can tell me where is a problem. If this variable is not touched or is assigned with different value it is working fine.  Thank You in advance.

**EDIT:**
Some of parser code: Part of grammar. If i dont touch counter it is working.

```
%{
    int counter = 0;
    int params[2];
    char* EXP = "NONE";
%}


%%
command       : identifier ASSGNOP expression';'                {gen_code(EXP,params,$1); counter = 0; }   


value  | identifier            { params[counter] = gen_variable($1,counter); counter++;       }


expression | value '+' value    {EXP = "ADD";}
```

Comment: At which line do you make the small code change? And what is the change?

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more information than that, since none of us can read over your shoulder. Please add relevant parts of your `parser.y` if you expect meaningful advice.

Comment: Plesea don't minus me. It is realy strange problem and i dont understand why it is happaning. It is not helping me. I updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like

```
b := 5 + a;
```

will execute the reduction

```
{ params[counter] = gen_variable($1,counter); counter++; }
```

three times.

But you declare:

```
int params[2];
```

So the third time, you'll be overwriting some random part of memory, after which almost anything could go wrong.

<editorial_comment>
Dynamic data structures are not difficult to write. Static memory allocations almost always get you into trouble.
</editorial_comment>

Comment: why the yyerror() is returning Syntax error then? U mean it is just random beceause sth went wrong with static memory?

Comment: @Dago: Once you overwrite memory which doesn't belong to you, *anything can happen*. I don't know why that particular thing happens. You've corrupted some internal variable in yyparse, and the parser is not working correctly as a result.

Comment: okey. I will check as fast as possible.